# Best way to port c++ game to web

Tags: javascript, c++, html, activex, google-nativeclient

I realize the above question is rather broad so I will narrow it down. I have a simple opengl c++ game engine that lives in a static library (could be converted to a dynamic lib).

I have been thinking of ways of getting it to run in web. From what I can see I could use ActiveX or Google NaCl to run the c++ code in browser. But these technologies do not seem easily cross platform? Or maybe I have misunderstood.

Another option I have seen is converting the engine to javascript and WebGL and running in an HTML5 canvas. Would this be slower than c++? It would be very cross platform though.

What do you think is the best option, or better yet is there any other option I have missed?

EDIT: what about a custom plugin similar to the unity webplayer?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple and portable way of doing that. The technologies involved differ too much. I know Quake III was "ported" to the web, but I believe they had to rewrite a lot of it.

Comment: So I have to write a different version for each web browser if I were to use ActiveX type technologies?

Answer (score 6):

There is a library created by @kripken which is still under development. It takes LLVM bitcode and convert into Javascript.

You can see the project page here, with working examples.
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest porting to NaCl.

**Advantages:**

1. **Performance:** You can use the full power of the CPU to render your game. If your game uses good 3d graphics or physics, you can make it look smooth even on old system configs. The performance of NaCl is comparable to Native OS applications, it only looses nearly 5 to 10% of FPS when I compared the same game to Win32 version.
2. There are a lot of already ported examples, games for NaCl that can help you do it easily.
3. It is already cross-platform. Chrome runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OSX.

**Disadvantages:**

1. Might take you around a week to port. You have to port to OpenGL ES 2.0 (However, it should be the same with any browser based methods, especially HTML5)
2. Runs only on Chrome.

Comment: I've ported Irrlicht Rendering Engine to NaCl and the performance is really good compared to any JavaScript based game performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something portable in a browser, then it has to rely on Javascript (and likely WebGL, although IE does not support that).

ActiveX and NaCL are just not portable in any way, shape or form.

I can't say which is easier, but you have an option of rewriting your game in Javascript, or using a tool like [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/) to compile your C++ to JavaScript.

Note that if you use the latter, it's still not a silver bullet. You'll likely have to make lots of changes to your code (for example because the libraries and APIs used in your C++ game won't be available on the browser)

Comment: Please note that PNaCL is perfectly portable. Currently for X86(-32,-64) and ARM, but it's can be extended to other platforms as it's based on LLVM bitcode. Operating system wise - currently it works under: Linux, Mac, ChromeOS, Windows... It's just not yet on mobile currently (however I don't see technical barriers, it looks like question of time). As question is not framed if it's about desktop/mobile or just cross-desktop compatibility, I would say that's it's portable cross-platform - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11685887/544721 .